# USAR FUNCTION CON PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estoy intentando definir una funcion que haga un update a la base de datos despues de un select. Pero al definirla, pareciera que no recibiera los parametros.
Lo estoy haciendo con ajax y y consulta la bd con php.

```
       include('../../control/parcel/db.php');

                     if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

                    $id = $_POST['id'];
                 $query = "SELECT * FROM reclute where id='$id'";
               $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


         if (!$result) {
                  die('Query Failed' . mysqli_error($connection));
                }

                $json = array();
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               $json[] = array(
                 'id' => $row['id']
            );

                   function LeerNotificacion($id)
                 {
           $query2 = "UPDATE reclute SET estado=('leido')
                   where id='$id';";
                   $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
                }
                 LeerNotificacion($id);
               }
                $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
             echo $jsonstring;
          }
```

me funciona si lo hago sin la function, pero quiero hacerlo con la function.
en ajax me da el error

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
   at Object.success (Datos_reclute.js:132)
  at c (jquery.min.js:2)
   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
   at l (jquery.min.js:2)
   at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Si haces un var_dump de $jsonstring que te arroja?

Comment: me faltaba incluir la conexion adentro de la funcion. la inclui y puse realizar el update. Pero veo q es un metodo muy feo estar pasandole la conexion a cada rato de la funcion. como puedo hacerlo de una mejor manera? tener siempre disponible esos valores de la conexion.?

Comment: Eso ya es una duda distinta, prometo sugiero resuelvas está publicando la solución

Comment: Por favor, pon el var_dump de $jsonstring o de $json.
Por cierto, definir una función en medio de un bucle while no es muy buena idea ya que si el bucle itera dos veces te dará error al intentar redifinir una función ya definida

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no haces el `UPDATE` directamente ¿? No necesitas para este caso hacer un `SELECT` y luego un `UPDATE`. Otra cosa es que no deberías resolver con `die` las ramas erróneas de tu código. El mensaje de error deja claro que Ajax espera un JSON en cualquier caso, debes proveerlo también para los errores algo así más o menos: `'error'=>'Mensaje de error'` y devolverlo con `json_encode` como haces con los datos. Luego en Ajax controlas si la respuesta tiene o no una clave `error`, dando así **coherencia a tu código**.

Comment: Crear funciones dentro de un ciclo seguramente dará error. En todo caso, declara la función fuera del `while` y llámala cuando sea necesario.